# How to change Page numbering start in phpword templateprocessor?

Tags: php, phpword

I had *.docx template file where in header i use page numbering.
But how in templateprocessor change PageNumberingStart number. Ive try to add section to template, but it doesnt work.
Is any ideas how to solve it?